# Unlocking bootloader for Vivo Y12

Tags: adb, fastboot, bootloader, bootloader-lock, vivo

I have enabled OEM unlock and USB debug from settings. I am using Vivo fastboot tool. And after entering the fastboot menu, I tried the code `fastboot bbk unlock_vivo`.

```
C:\Users\dell\Desktop\vivo_fastboot_for_windows>fastboot devices
MNFM7PSSGM75SKBY        fastboot

C:\Users\dell\Desktop\vivo_fastboot_for_windows>fastboot bbk unlock_vivo
...
FAILED (remote:  unclock fail.)
finished. total time: 0.004s
```

I tried various solutions on the internet but couldn't find one.

Please someone help me.

Comment: LOL the typo seems to be located in the modified vivo fastboot version you use. According to some blog on newer devices you have to use `fastboot bbk vivo_bsp unlock_vivo`

Comment: @Robert so how should I resolve and unlock my bootloader

Comment: @Robert I tried that command as well but it says unknown command

Comment: https://github.com/bkerler/mtkclient#unlock-bootloader

Answer (score 1):

Vivo devices with a Mediatek chipset don't allow anyone to unlock the bootloaders. The Qualcomm device's bootloaders can be unlocked by the unofficial EDL method discussed by XDA Developers. Sadly, my device is also based on the Mediatek chipset.

Please be patient until the Vivo developers officially release any method to unlock the bootloaders.

Answer (score -1):

Try this. I see on the system to unlock the bootloader, there is this command. Remember to type one by one.

```
fastboot flashing unlock
fastboot flashing unlock_critical
fastboot flashing get_unlock_ability
```

The problem is that even though I want to try it, there is no laptop or PC at home.

Comment: Just want to confirm if you're sure this command will work on Vivo Y12 or other Vivo devices? OEM unlock can have different commands per vendor.

Comment: yes i think it will work on vivo y12

Comment: @VickyZakaria no it won't, and you haven't tested. that's just the common google unlock method. vivo hasn't implemented that commands this way. please note the *'fastboot bbk unlock_vivo'* in question