# Root vivo y91i without unlocking bootloader

Tags: rooting, 8.1-oreo, vivo

Is it possible to gain root access for vivo y91i by patching the `boot.img` by Magisk, placing the patched `boot.img` in the place of the original `boot.img` in the stock ROM, and flashing the entire firmware as an update via local upgrade feature in vivo? Will it work? And if it fails, how badly it can wreck my device?

Comment: won't work because of avb2.0 (and missing zip signature)

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232574 https://android.stackexchange.com/q/241355 https://android.stackexchange.com/q/241595